# Laravel Tinker shows old values from the collection

Tags: php, mongodb, laravel, homestead, tinker

I have a Laravel model named Campaigns (made using a jenssegers mongodb extension). When I echo this function:

```
$campaigns = Campaigns::all();
echo($campaigns);
```

I get correct values. But whenever I try the same from a Command in a schedule or through Artisan Tinker, I get old, non-existing values used before in testing on my local machine. I tried clearing cache and all the config, but it didn't work. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `>>> $campaigns = Campaigns::all();
[!] Aliasing 'Campaigns' to 'App\Campaigns' for this Tinker session.`

And after that Tinker dumps the $campaigns variable showing me wrong values

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer. For anyone with a similar problem: If you run MongoDB on Homestead it creates its own instance on the virtual server and logs in without using any credentials. Get the ID of your running Vagrant process by typing `vagrant global-status` and ssh into it by `vagrant ssh 1a2b3c`. Then just run Mongo on the virtual server and compare your values.

Answer (score -1):

Because echo print the only variable not the array and **$campaigns = Campaigns::all();** gives the array.
**You should try below way to show the data.**

```
$campaigns = Campaigns::all();
print_r($campaigns);
```

Comment: It just changes the formatting, but still get wrong values

Comment: @version_control when you try my code, which error was arrived?

Comment: I don't get any error. I just get values from a MongoDB collection that don't exist and were removed by me before.